# Short story about government agents shadowing a man in an alien's dream

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story, possibly from the early 1960s. It's about government agents shadowing an ordinary man to keep him out of harm's way at all costs. Evidently, this one man is the product of a sleeping entity's dream, and if the man were to come to harm, then reality would cease to exist.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? Also, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: Is the story from the man's point of view, one of the agents, or a general omniscient narrator?  How does the government know this will happen?

Comment: Hi I think I read it in the late sixties or early seventies. I think it was in an anthology.

Comment: The story is from the point of view from a new agent.

Comment: Sounds like ["Tonight the Sky Will Fall"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?78499) by Daniel F. Galouye, which was also the answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133447/trying-to-identify-an-old-story-about-a-man-who-wonders-why-his-luck-is-always-g). You can read it for free at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Imagination_v03n03_1952-05_LennyS-cape1736/mode/2up). Is that the one you were looking for?

Comment: No sorry this isn't the story.

Comment: I suspect that I did read it in an anthology, but it was a long time ago.

Comment: @Vedoo *Tonight the Sky Will Fall* is a perfect fit to your description. If we're to identify your story we'll need to know how it differs from this.

Comment: Would it be "Prototaph" by Keith Laumer, https://hell.pl//szymon/Baen/The%20Baltic%20War/The%20Lighter%20Side/0743435370__21.htm ? If so, I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["Tonight the Sky Will Fall!"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?78499), a novella by [Daniel F. Galouye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_F._Galouye) which was also the answer to the old question [Trying to identify an old story about a man who wonders why his luck is always good](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133447/trying-to-identify-an-old-story-about-a-man-who-wonders-why-his-luck-is-always-g). It was originally published in [*Imagination*, May 1952](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58899+c), which is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Imagination_v03n03_1952-05_LennyS-cape1736/mode/2up); reprinted in the 1974 anthology [*Space Opera*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?31428) ([Brian W. Aldiss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Aldiss), ed.). Galouye's  two novellas "Tonight the Sky Will Fall!" and its 1955 sequel ["The Day the Sun Died"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?84318) (in [*Imagination*, December 1955](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58857+c), also at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Imagination_v06n09_1955-12_UnkSc/mode/2up)) were incorporated into the 1973 novel [*The Infinite Man*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7604), which has a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinite_Man).

The main character is Tarl Brent, the man who hosts the cosmic dreamer. In the following excerpt two of the agents assigned to protect Tarl, his chauffeur Charles and his girlfriend Marcella, explain things to him as reality is starting to break down:

> "Tarl," Marcella said, placing a hand on his shoulder. "You were right. You were being followed—followed every minute—every second. But it was by persons who meant only good! Persons who only intended that you shouldn't be harmed, that you remained out of trouble, that you became wealthy. They provided everything that would make you happy, keep you content . . ."
>
> "Even women?" Tarl brushed her hand off his shoulder. "They even wanted to see I was well supplied with women?"
>
> Keeping her eyes away from his, Marcella said with effort, "Yes."
>
> "And you, Marcella, are you one of them?"
>
> She was silent for an eternity."Yes, Tarl. I am one of them."
>
> "And I am too, Tarl," said Charles. "Almost everybody you know is."
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "It's this way, Tarl." Charles leaned close to him. "The best scientific minds in the country found out something a little over three years ago. They found out what they called "the true nature of our world—of the entire universe . . ."
>
> The chauffeur stared directly into his eyes. "*It ain't!" he blurted. "*None of it is real!* Nothing at all is real—not in any physical sense . . . *It's all an illusion!* This car. Marcella. That building. This planet. *Every star in the sky!*
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "Oh, Tarl!" she cried. "I keep thinking that you're *it!* And I keep wanting to draw away from you. But you're in the same boat with everyone else. You are as imaginary, as unreal, as everything else! But it's not you I'm afraid of. It's the *intellect* that shares your body and your mind!"
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "Tarl," Charles continued. "That thing—that *intellect* within you—is the only thing that really exists. Nothing else exists. Not even space. Not even time. Not even matter. Only that *intellect*—that intangible, bodiless power of reasoning—is real! *That and that alone is the universe—the entire eniverse.* All that is, exists only by virtue of *its* imagination!"
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "You see," Marcella held his limp hand again, "those who have been following you, and their directors believe that only a simple world—a simple universe—was created by the thing while it was in conscious state.
>
> "They suspect that only in the subconscious, sleepful stage did everything become complete . . . Perhaps while it was consciously in control of its creation it created only you—maybe one or two other persons—a small glade as a dwelling place—merely a handful of the simple essentials.
>
> "Then, content and peaceful in satisfaction with itself, it lapsed into a lethargy. While it basked in the slumber of that satisfaction, the intellect extended its creation without conscious effort. The glade became a valley. The valley a continent. The continent a world. Then there came other worlds and stars and stellar systems, and complexity of systematism, order, sciences . . ."
>
> For the first time Tarl's eyes took on a faint glow of partial comprehension. "And," he said, "if it awakes, it can't hold together the complexity of the things it has created!"
>
> The girl nodded.